# Get data for past three years starting from January

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am writing a query in which I need to get data for the past three years.  What I'm looking to capture is the past three years starting from the month of January to now.  This needs to be dynamic adding months to 2022 as time passes while retaining the entire history for 2019.

Unfortunately, mine is showing three year history from today's date (36 months, dropping January of 2019.

**Query:**

`WHERE  PDBC.PDBC_EFF_DT >= DATEADD(YEAR,-3,GETDATE())`

`WHERE  PDBC.PDBC_EFF_DT >= '01/01/2019'`

works but don't want to update this year after
year as it is embedded in excel.

**Output:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC0G8.png

**Need:**

January 2019 through now with the min date changing to January of 2020 next year.

**Fix:**

Thanks for everyone's input, learned a bit from each of your comments and figured it out or so I think...

```
WHERE 
YEAR(PDBC.PDBC_EFF_DT) BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - 3 AND YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Comment: If you'd included the full query, I'd be able to put a proper answer - but if you use a variable to represent the first of January this year (instead of `GETDATE()`) then it'll help.

Comment: `datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 3, 1, 1)` will give you the "1st of January of three years back". Ie, it will give the 2019-01-01, if you execute this on any day in year 2022

Comment: Think about it, `GETDATE()` returns the **current** date and time. So, right now it would return a value along the lines of `2022-01-05 17:20:37.423` (UTC). If you subtract 3 years from that, you get `2019-01-05 17:20:37.423`; you're missing 4 days ~17 hours of data.#

Comment: The requirement is ambiguous. `capture is the past three years (Jan - Dec)` but your existing `WHERE` clause _only says_ `>=`. So do you want only data in 2019, 2020, and 2021? Or all data from Jan 1 2019 to right now? If the former then when do you shift to 2020, 2021, and 2022?

Answer (score 2):

The comment above showed the right way to determine the starting point:

```
DECLARE @start datetime 
        = DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - 3, 1, 1);
```

The right way to query the data in the table based on this time frame - to ensure you *might* use any existing or future indexes on the datetime column - is with a range predicate:

```
WHERE date_eff_dt >= @start
```

The requirements were unclear, but if you only want the data *within those three years* and nothing that has happened *this year*, just add an end bound:

```
  AND date_eff_dt < DATEADD(YEAR, 3, @start)
```

Or you could flip it the other way around:

```
DECLARE @end datetime
        = DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), 1, 1);

SELECT 
  ...
WHERE date_eff_dt >= DATEADD(YEAR, -3, @end)
  AND date_eff_dt <  @end;
```

Answer (score 0):

try comparing year to year in the filter:

```sql
where DatePart(Year,date_eff_dt) >=DatePart(Year,GetDate())-3
```

Comment: let me refractor it  DatePart(Year,GetDate())-3.  Super easy repair

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8dfc655e6d47273dda13b374f3a2dd89

Comment: Point still stands about `DatePart(Year,date_eff_dt) >=` - this is just a way to ensure you scan the entire table every single time.

Comment: Yes. It will scan the complete table.  You can populate a field with the year only then see if the explain plan will optimize.  A non clustered index can be applied to the year

Comment: ...or just index the datetime column, which might already exist.

Answer (score 0):

The earlier answer should work if you are looking for all data after 3 years ago. I could be misinterpreting your question but I believe you are looking for 3 full calendar years of data. I would use the following pattern:

```
WHERE YEAR(date_eff_dt) BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - 3 AND YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
```

Comment: Also applying `YEAR()` to the column renders indexes useless. Why not `>= Jan 1 2019 AND < Jan 1 2022`?